# Comparison of slopes of certain line bundles on surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $(X, H)$ be a smooth complex polarized algebraic surface and let $L_1, L_2$ be two line bundles on $X$ and $F$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$ such that there exists a non-trivial homomorphism between $L_1 \otimes F \to L_2$. This means that slopes of $L_1 \otimes F $ and $L_2$ with respect to $H$ can't be the same (Please correct me if I am wrong).

At this point my question is the following : Can we expect $\text{slope}(L_1) \leq \text{slope}(L_2)$?

Any help from anyone is welcome

Comment: What if $F=L_1^{-1}\otimes L_2$? Or do you have a different notion of `nontrivial homomorphism'?

Comment: @Mohan, I forgot to mention that $F$ is not a line bundle. To be precise in my situation $F$ is the ideal sheaf of a zero dimensional subscheme.

Comment: I still don't understand. If $L_1=L_2$, there is always a non-trivial homomorphism $L_1\otimes F\to L_2$ where $F$ is a non-zero ideal sheaf. Notice also that in this case, whatever line bundles $L_i$ are, there is a non-trivial map $L_1\to L_2$ by double dualizing and thus your slope inequality is correct.

Comment: @Mohan, thank you for the answer. Again in my specific case it's $L_1 \neq L_2$